# Ignoring the git folder over FTP

Tags: git, ftp

I know that it is possible to PUSH an FTP rep using something like :

```
git push ftp://host.net/path/to/repo.git/
```

My question however , is if it is possible to transfer the actual working files over ftp ( even "normal" GUI based ftp that a secretary could understand ) while telling it to IGNORE all the `.git` dir as a whole ?

The point is that while working on git, sometimes we need to deploy only the working files to the server , and the .git directory takes more time to upload than the files themselves .

I am not sure if I am looking for an `FTP` command (ignore X folder or file) or something in `.git`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you're looking for a way to export the contents of your git repo and deploy it over FTP to a remote directory such that it takes the least amount of time to transfer the files.

Git does not provide support for exporting and deploying to a FTP server directly, but there are few good scripts that can help you achieve what you're looking for by uploading only the files which have changed:

- [`git-ftp`](https://github.com/ezyang) by Edward Z. Yang:

  > Some web hosts only give you FTP access to the hosting space, but you
  >   would still like to use Git to version the contents of your directory.
  >   You could upload a full tarball of your website every time you update
  >   but that's wasteful. git-ftp.py only uploads the files that changed.
- [`git-ftp`](https://github.com/resmo/git-ftp) by René Moser

  > I use git-ftp for my script based projects, mostly PHP. Most of the
  >   low-cost web hosting companies do not provide SSH or git support, but
  >   only FTP.
  >
  > That is why I needed an easy way to deploy my git tracked projects.
  >   Instead of transfering the whole project, I thought, why not only
  >   transfer the files that changed since the last time, git can tell me
  >   those files.
  >
  > Even if you are playing with different branches, git-ftp knows which
  >   files are different. No ordinary FTP client can do that.

Comment: thanks for those resources, they look great , but is it possible to do over a normal GUI ftp ? like Drag and Drop a folder , but ignoring the .git files ? I ssume that is an FTP feature more than .git , but is it possible ??

Comment: Yes it depends on the GUI you use. Some GUIs might offer rsync-equivalent support in their GUI for updating the files on the remote. Check out the popular ones like `filezilla`, they might already have it.